# Execute MySQL query with checkbox using PHP AJAX MYSQL without page refresh?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

Please help me with my AJAX .
I am developing a page through PHP to manage account permission. But my query is not working , no errors reported.

**This is the HTML and PHP code.**

```
<?php $permission = $list_data['permit'];?>
         <div class="col-lg-12 bt-switch">
         <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $list_data['id']; ?>">
         <input type="checkbox" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" data-on- 
              color="success" data-off-color="danger" data-on-text="Active" 
              data-off-text="Blocked" data-size="mini"   
                  <?php
                     if($permission==1){
                               echo " checked";
                                       }
                      ?> >
             </div>
```

**This is the Ajax Code :**
*Latest Jquery is included before this code.*

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bt-switch').click(function(){
        var hiddenValueID = $(this).children(':hidden').val();
        if ($(this).children(':checked').length == 0)
        {
            var valueData = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            var valueData = 1;
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "insertdata.php",
            data: {value: valueData, id: hiddenValueID}
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

Is the code in AJAX correct to fetch the **hidden** and **checkbox** type value?

**This the php Code on the insertdata.php**

```
<?php
  include_once ('db.php');
      if(isset($_POST['value'])){
          $id=$_POST['id'];
         $value=$_POST['value'];
        $user_blocked_query="update login set permit='$value' where id=$id";
            if(mysqli_query($conn , $user_blocked_query)==TRUE){

              }
         }
  ?>
```

*Can any one fix this for me , please?*

Comment: You won't get errors if you don't look for them. Use the error reporting functions. Also you are open to SQL injections. Parameterize. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Can you confirm that the individual pieces work? Meaning if you change your jquery code to show an alert instead of posting ajax data, do you see the alert?

Comment: I also would advise opening the developer console and watching the request. If the values are being sent correctly to the PHP than this is just a PHP/mysql issue and the Jquery/ajax tags and code can be removed. The simpler you make the easier it is to help you.

Comment: If you don't know what the developer tools are, this helps: [What_are_browser_developer_tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools)

Comment: I made it happen simply on a button , but the page start refreshing.To fix the issue , i am using ajax.

Comment: The data is print in a table. A While loop is used.

Comment: Please help to apply the checkbox instead of buttons . I am using Elite admin Template in my project.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.